# Fold all methods in a Python class with Evil

Tags: evil, code-folding, vim-emulation

How can I fold all the methods in a Python class?  I use Evil and would prefer a pure Evil solution, if possible.

I'm looking for a quick way to take something like this:

```
class LongClassIDidNotWrite():

    def method1():
        junk...
        junk...
        junk...

    def method2():
        junk...
        junk...
        junk...

    def method3():
        junk...
        junk...
        junk...
```

and make it look like this:

```
class LongClassIDidNotWrite():

    def method1():    
    def method2():    
    def method3():
```

I don't care if it has a `...` at the end of the line or has a pretty `{{{}}}` notation telling me the number of lines folded.  I just want it to fold!

I know I can press `zc` within a method to fold it.  If I try something like `VGzc`, it doesn't fold.  The fastest thing I've come up with is to record a macro `qazc]]q` and then replay it doing something like `100@a`.

Looking at how Vim does it, posts say to `:set foldmethod=indent`.  To which Evil says,

> "State foldmethod=indent cannot be set as initial Evil state".

I've tried `vimish-fold`, along with `evil-vimish-fold` as well as `origami`.  I can't get them to fold the methods within a class like above.  They supposedly "just work".  But that's not what I'm experiencing.  Before I waste more time doing trial-and-error and scrounging, is there something I'm missing?  It seems like this problem would be solved already.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Im having the exact same issue and have yet to find a working solution.

Comment: Assuming your point/cursor is on the `class ... ` line, `hs-hide-level` will collapse everything with in the class, giving you your requested output. This would be unlike `hs-hide-block` which would collapse the entire class to one line.

Comment: @nega, that's precisely what I was looking for! :)  Throw that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not documented well enough, and possibly poorly named, but the `hideshow` function `hs-hide-level` will collapse all the blocks within the current block. That is, if your cursor is on the `class ...` line (or below it) in your example input, it will give you something very similar to your desired output. Since `hideshow` works with indentation I've found that it works best with *well formated* code or text.

Given:

```python
class LongClassIDidNotWrite():

    def method1():
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")

    def method2():
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")

    def method3():
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")
```

Placing the cursor in "Long" on the `class ...` line and calling `M-x hs-hide-level` or `C-c @ C-l` will give you:

```python
class LongClassIDidNotWrite():

    def method1():...)

    def method2():...)

    def method3():...)
```

This works on any point that is part of the `class ...` block. That is, that line, on the blank lines, and on the `def ...` lines. If you try it on the `print ...` lines it won't work, as you're in a new block, and there are no child blocks to fold.

`hs-hide-level` also runs a hook `hs-hide-hook` which could prove useful.

There is also a `hs-hide-level-recursive` which will recursively hide blocks in a region. It does not run `hs-hide-hook`, according to its documentation.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the method given in the question, although not efficient, is sufficient.  Let me explain it in greater detail.  Assuming you have `evil-mode` enabled:

1. Toggle `hs-minor-mode` to enable folding
2. Place your cursor at the first column of a `def` statement line.  This can be done by pressing `0`
3. Record a macro which folds the current section and then moves to the next section: `qazc]]q`.

   - `q`: begin recording a macro
   - `a`: name the new macro "a"
   - `zc`: close the current section (fold the section)
   - `]]`: go to the next section via `evil-forward-section-begin`
   - `q`: finish recording the macro
4. Replay the macro 100 times: `100@a`

   - `100`: the number of times to call the macro
   - `@a`: call macro with name "a"

Replace 100 with whatever number of folds you want to make.  Or, simply repeat the macro call with `@@`.

---

I found that the real question I had was something like, *"How can I get a quick overview of a class's methods?"* or *"How can I quickly navigate my code?"*

To this end, `elpy-mode` has `elpy-occur-definitions` which lists all `class` and `def` statements with the `occur` function.

I find the defaults for `occur` clunky.  Here is how I adjust the behavior to my tastes.

```lisp
(evil-mode)                              ; enable evil mode
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'elpy-mode)  ; always use elpy-mode with python files

;; Make *Occur* window size to the contents
(setq fit-window-to-buffer-horizontally t)
(add-hook 'occur-hook
       (lambda ()
         (save-selected-window
           (pop-to-buffer "*Occur*")
           (fit-window-to-buffer))))

;; Make *Occur* window always open on the right side
(setq
 display-buffer-alist
 `(("\\*Occur\\*"
    display-buffer-in-side-window
    (side . right)
    (slot . 0)
    (window-width . fit-window-to-buffer))))

;; Automatically switch to *Occur* buffer 
(add-hook 'occur-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Occur*")))

;; Modify *Occur* buffer navigation
;;; Set initial state of *Occur* buffer to normal mode
(evil-set-initial-state 'occur-mode 'normal)

;;; Use q or ESC to quit close the *Occur* window
(evil-define-key 'normal occur-mode-map (kbd "q") 'quit-window)
(evil-define-key 'normal occur-mode-map (kbd "<escape>") 'quit-window)

;;; Use TAB or SPC to show the occurrence in the other window
(evil-define-key 'normal occur-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'occur-mode-display-occurrence)
(evil-define-key 'normal occur-mode-map (kbd "SPC") 'occur-mode-display-occurrence)

;;; Use <return> to jump to the occurrence and close the *Occur* window
(evil-define-key 'normal occur-mode-map (kbd "<return>") '(lambda () (interactive)
                                (occur-mode-goto-occurrence-other-window)
                                (kill-buffer "*Occur*")))
```

Comment: Nice tweaks to `occur`

Comment: What is `occur`? I can not find this in the elpy docs.

Comment: @buhtz, It's a native Emacs function to show all lines matching a pattern. See `C-h f occur` for details.