# Fold code between parentheses and brackets in python mode + hideshow

Tags: code-folding, inferior-python-mode

I'm working on a plotly dash app where there are a number of nested blocks of code like the following:

```
dbc.Row(
        [
            dbc.Col(
                [
                <some long code>
                ]
            ),
            dbc.Col(
                [
                <another piece of code>
                ]
            ),
        ]
    ),
```

I would like to be able to fold the code between two matching bracket or parentheses symbols. My init file has the following configuration for `hs` (taken from the [hide show emacswiki page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow)) and it does what I want if I switch to `R-mode` (*i.e.* fold the code using `C-+` when the cursor is at a symbol) . Then, of course,  all the python functionalities are off. Is there a way to fold the code between brackets within python mode. Ideally a custom mode/function that I can toggle when working with dash apps. Thanks

```
(defun toggle-selective-display (column)
(interactive "P")
(set-selective-display
 (or column
     (unless selective-display
       (1+ (current-column))))))

(defun toggle-hiding (column)
(interactive "P")
(if hs-minor-mode
    (if (condition-case nil
            (hs-toggle-hiding)
          (error t))
        (hs-show-all))
  (toggle-selective-display column)))

;; Define Keybindings for hiding/showing code
(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") 'toggle-hiding)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-\\") 'toggle-selective-display)
(add-hook 'ess-r-mode-hook (lambda () (hs-minor-mode 1)))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (hs-minor-mode 1)))
```

Comment: I've never gotten Python folding to work the way I want with `hideshow` or `origami.el`. When I need it, I reach for marker based folding with `folding.el`. The only thing I ever got working was folding general code blocks as in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50144/12713. My only suggestions would be to try the other python mode (https://melpa.org/#/python-mode) with `hideshow` or maybe there's a Treesitter based solution out there, though I'm ignorant of the current state of Treesitter and Emacs (other than it's "in" Emacs 29). Hopefully someone else will will have a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It worked out of the box with [yafolding](https://github.com/zenozeng/yafolding.el). Just enabled it and code can be folded with `C-intro` even lists with a large number of elements :)